# how do I write to a spawned terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, tcl, expect, tk-toolkit

For this little script:

```
package require Tcl 8.4
package require Expect 5.40

spawn gnome-terminal

while {1} {
    puts -nonewline "Enter your name: "
    flush stdout
    set name [gets stdin]    
    puts "Hello $name"
}
```

how can I write to the spawned `gnome-terminal` so that user input is echoed to both terminals?

Comment: You can't. Expect can control a command-line application, and gnome-terminal is a GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run Expect *inside* the gnome-terminal, not the other way round. Expect is a command-line program really, and gnome-terminal is really not (it's a graphical terminal emulator). In particular, gnome-terminal ignores its stdin and stdout entirely; it effectively creates those for other programs to use. Meanwhile, Expect controls other programs by talking to their stdin and stdout (with trickery with extra virtual terminals); this means that the interface it uses to its subprocesses is something that gnome-terminal basically ignores from the outside.

Though in this case, why not use Tk to pop up a GUI to ask for the password instead? Instead of putting up a proxy to ask the question, you can ask it directly. This can make for a much richer interface if you desire…

Comment: Because my tcl is limited to what is above.  Can I manually open two terminals and send messages between them somehow?  With the comm package?  If it can't be done, or only reasonably done with TK, then that's just how the cookie crumbles.  Just want to know.